# How to break .map function

Tags: reactjs, react-native

how to break a .map function? Code samples attached below.
I want to break the look once the index reached at 5 because I only want to render 5 Avatar to the screen.

```
<View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', marginTop: 20, marginLeft: 30  }}>
    {
      peopleGroup.map((people, i) => {
        if(i<5) {
          return (
            <Avatar
              key={people.id}
              width={30}
              position='absolute'
              containerStyle={{ transform: [{translate: [-28 + (28 * i), 0, 1 - (i * 0.1)]}] }}
              small
              rounded
              source={{uri: people.image}}
              activeOpacity={0.7}
              />
          )
        }else if(i===5) {
          return (
          <View key={i} style={{ transform: [{translate: [(25 * i), 9, 0]}]  }}>
            <Text>{peopleGroup.length}</Text>
          </View>
          )
        }
      }
      )
    }
</View>
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Use [`Array.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice#parameters) before you map.

```
peopleGroup
.slice(0, 5) // creates a copy of original, 5 items long
.map(...) // subsequent operations work on the copy
```

Tada!

Answer (score 4):

> How to break a .map function?

Not possible, We can't break [#array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), it will run for each element of array.

To solve your problem, you can use [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) first then map, [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) first 5 elements of array then run map on that.

Like this:

```
peopleGroup.slice(0,5).map((people, i) => {
    return (...)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

instead of using [`.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) and [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) which will create another loop.
You can use [`.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), that way you are doing your logic with one loop (better performance).
The difference is that `.map` will have to return the same length of the array, where `.reduce` can return anything actually.

```
  data.reduce((result, current, i) => {
    if (i < 5) {
      result.push(<div>{current}</div>);
    }
    return result;
  }, [])
```

Running example:

```js
const data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];

const App = () => (
  <div>
    {data.reduce((result, current, i) => {
      if (i < 5) {
        result.push(<div>{current}</div>);
      }
      return result;
    }, [])}
  </div>
);

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: `Array.reduce` is the bomb.

Comment: One drawback to using `Array.reduce` is that, if the input array is a million items long, the reduce iterator will execute a million times. If you only want to work with the first 5 items, a million iterations is a high price to pay. I assume `Array.slice` wouldn't perform a million operations under the covers, although it'd be better to do that in the engine than in app code if it has to be done.

Answer (score 1):

```js
throw new Error(e);
```

add it in `try catch` for preventing crash.