# Add stop condition to map in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx

Having the following code snippet:

```
<TableHead>
  {documents.map((docs, i) => (
    <TableRow key={i}>
      <TableCell>
       {{docs.name}
      </TableCell>
    </TableRow>
  ))}
</TableHead>
```

How can I make it run only for a finite number of iterations? In my particular case I want it to run for 10 times.

Tried to add a condition like `i < 10 && ...` but it doesn't work.

```
<TableHead>
  {documents.map((docs, i) => (
   { i < 10 &&
    <TableRow key={i}>
      <TableCell>
       {{docs.name}
      </TableCell>
    </TableRow>
   }
  ))}
</TableHead>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Then don't use map. Map is used when you want to transform every item in an array. Use a for loop instead.

Comment: Take a `slice` or use a loop?

Comment: Slice upto 10 and then map

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to break .map function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48248067/how-to-break-map-function)

Comment: @aayush good catch :)

Answer (score 1):

Slice the first 10 elements of the array:

```
 documents.slice(0, 10).map(/*...*/)
```

Comment: About to give the same answer

Comment: So you answer the question and mark it as duplicate at the same time?

Comment: @tushar no, I searched for a duplicate, didn't find one, then answered, then agreed to the duplicate proposed by another user.

Comment: I don't see any valid reason to delete the answer now that it is there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `filter` `documents` before `map`ing

```
<TableHead>
    {documents
        .filter((doc, i) => i < 10)
        .map((doc, i) => (
            <TableRow key={i} >
                <TableCell>
                    {doc.name}
                </TableCell>
            </TableRow>
        ))
    }
</TableHead>
```

Comment: filter will iterate over each item, which isn't necessary